# Redirect user after submiting ajax form in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to submit form in colorbox via ajax with jquery. This is my problem : 
 first : i can't redirect  user to another page after submiting the form. 
second : i want in another case to change colorbox content wihtout closing it.
NB: i'm using Codeingiter.
This my jquery code  :

```
 $('#create-list-form').submit(function(){
        $.post(
        $(this).attr('action'),
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
         $.colorbox({html: data});
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using ajax? The whole point of it (usually) is so forms when submitted don't redirect.

Comment: you really haven't explained issues with enough detail. You have 2 cases... treat them separately so people can understand what code goes to what case.. and exact behavior you want